# my way of cloning html node does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginner java script learner and following some online tutorials to improve.
I am not quite why my code does not work and I don't see any thing wrong when I have chrome developer tool open? If any one could tip me about what I am doing wrong here it will be really appreciated.
What I undrestood after logging I realized that in `var the_node= document.getElementById("hh").lastChild;` the_node is still undefined

```
<doctype! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>clone a node</title>
    <script>
        function cloneNode1() {
            var the_node= document.getElementById("hh").lastChild;
            var cloned_node = the_node.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById("hh").appendChild(cloned_node);
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>welcome to Sarah's page</h1>
    <h2>here is the list of things which I really like</h2>
    <ul id="hh">
        <li>painting</li>
        <li>cooking</li>
    </ul>
    <p>click on the buttom to add to the list</p>
    <button onclick="cloneNode1()"> click me to colne</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `element.lastChild` returns last child node whether it is an element node, a text node or a comment node. In your case, it returns text node, which contains new line character. Whitespace inside elements is considered as text, and text is considered as nodes.

In order to make it more clear, it will work if you remove all whitespaces in your `hh` element:

```js
function cloneNode1() {
  var the_node= document.getElementById("hh").lastChild;
  var cloned_node = the_node.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("hh").appendChild(cloned_node);
}
```

```html
<ul id="hh"><li>painting</li><li>cooking</li></ul>
<button onclick="cloneNode1()"> click me to colne</button>
```

However, you don't need to do this. You only need to use **`element.lastElementChild`**, if you want to extract the last child element.

Here is the snippet, which works after changing the method:

```js
function cloneNode1() {
  var the_node= document.getElementById("hh").lastElementChild;
  var cloned_node = the_node.cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById("hh").appendChild(cloned_node);
}
```

```html
<ul id="hh">
  <li>painting</li>
  <li>cooking</li>
</ul>
<button onclick="cloneNode1()"> click me to colne</button>
```